# My app gets launched but does not reopen

Tags: android, firebase

My app gets launched but does not reopen. It shows the following error in my logcat -

> myapplicationfirebase V/FA: onActivityCreated myapplicationfirebase
>   **E/ANDR-PERF-JNI: IPerf::tryGetService failed!**
>
> myapplicationfirebase D/FA: Connected to remote service
>
> myapplicationfirebase V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
>
> myapplicationfirebase V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
>   .myapplicationfirebase W/DynamiteModule: **Local module descriptor
>   class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.**

Comment: did you imported in your gradle : app module your firebase auth dependencies ?, current compile is com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0

Comment: Can you check what you have in `onResume` of your activity ? also if you have one already , can you make sure you have `super.onResume()` called on first line ?

Comment: I have my import as -
implementation ' com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
this was added automatically when i connected to firebase authentication

Comment: I dont have an onResume method as of yet.